# How to fix a property list file on applescript?

Tags: applescript

I have been working on a "notification previewer" applet for a while and I wanted to try and save notification data when the process is done.

When I added the .plist snippet of code into it I get an error that says "Cant get property list file in /~/~/~/~/~/~" (the random number at the end is a randomly generated number for the .plist).

Here is the code. Can anybody help me figure out whats wrong?

```applescript
on getTimeInHoursAndMinutes()
    -- Get the "hour"
    set timeStr to time string of (current date)
    set Pos to offset of ":" in timeStr
    set theHour to characters 1 thru (Pos - 1) of timeStr as string
    set timeStr to characters (Pos + 1) through end of timeStr as string
    
    -- Get the "minute"
    set Pos to offset of ":" in timeStr
    set theMin to characters 1 thru (Pos - 1) of timeStr as string
    set timeStr to characters (Pos + 1) through end of timeStr as string
    
    --Get "AM or PM"
    set Pos to offset of " " in timeStr
    set theSfx to characters (Pos + 1) through end of timeStr as string
    
    return (theHour & ":" & theMin & " " & theSfx) as string
end getTimeInHoursAndMinutes

set thetime to getTimeInHoursAndMinutes()

set ThePLISTNAME to random number from 0 to 1.0E+17

set A1 to display dialog "Enter in your title" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Notification Previewer"

set TITLE to text returned of A1

set A2 to display dialog "Enter in your text" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Notification Previewer"

set TEXT2 to text returned of A2

set A3 to display dialog "Enter in your subtitle" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Notification Previewer"

set TEXT3 to text returned of A3

set A4 to display dialog "choose a sound, LIST: Basso Blow Bottle Frog Funk Glass Hero Morse Ping Pop Purr Sosumi Submarine Tink. (CASE SENSITIVE)" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 with title "Notification Previewer"

set TEXT4 to text returned of A4

display notification TEXT2 with title TITLE subtitle TEXT3 sound name TEXT4

set textdata to {"Title: ", TITLE, "Text: ", TEXT2, "Subtitle: ", TEXT3, "Sound: ", TEXT4}

tell application "System Events"
    set theParentDictionary to make new property list item with properties {kind:record, name:ThePLISTNAME}
    
    --set fold to alias "~/Applications/Notification Previewer/Contents/Resources/Contents/Saves/"
    
    --set TextFile to make new file at fold with properties {name:thetime, file type:"PLIST", creator type:"ttxt", type:«class fsrf»}
    
    set thePropertyListFilePath to ("~/Applications/Notification Previewer/Contents/Resources/Contents/Saves/" & ThePLISTNAME & ".plist/")
    
    set thePropertyListFile to make new property list file with properties {contents:theParentDictionary, name:thePropertyListFilePath}
    
    tell property list items of thePropertyListFile
        make new property list item at end with properties {kind:string, name:"stringKey", value:textdata}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Have a look at: [Working with Property List Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WorkwithPropertyListFiles.html)

Comment: Just an FYI, changing the _value_ of `set thePropertyListFilePath to` _to_ `("~/Desktop/" & ThePLISTNAME & ".plist")` for testing purposes... the _script_ completed without errors. That said, the layout of the .plist _file_ is not a good layout IMO.